# how to make the scroll view for iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, user-interface, scrollview

HI

May i know how to make the scroll view as mentioned in this following URL.

http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TextandWeb/TextandWeb.html

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView).